# PHP: preg_match & explode to get some random code from url

Tags: php, regex

I want to get some random code from URL beginning with some word (`d_` and `r_`)

Example:

```
 1. domain.com/index/book-one-d_123456
 2. domain.com/index/book-one-r_123456
```

I want to show if the link is "d_123456" show content for "d_123456" and if "r_123456" show content for "r_123456". And explode random code after "d_" or "r_".

I have tried with:

```
if ($co){
$rand = explode('/',$co);

if (preg_match('/^.*([d_]).*?$/i', $rand[1]))
{
$res = explode("d_",$rand[1]);
some code..........
{
else if (preg_match('/^.*([r_]).*?$/i', $soid[1]))
{
$res = explode("r_",$rand[1]);
some code..........
}
```

I can get random code from "d_" but I can't get it working for "r_" or seems not detecting.

---

for I'm sorry I posted to early and Thanks for your help guys :D
already found a solution from this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366744/5118751

I just change :

```
if ($co){
$rand = explode('/',$co);

if (preg_match('/d_/', $rand[1]))
{
$res = explode("d_",$rand[1]);
some code..........
{
else if (preg_match('/r_/', $soid[1]))
{
$res = explode("r_",$rand[1]);
some code..........
}
```

and now everthing working perfect ...

Comment: But `$rand[1]` is going to be `index` which is not the delimiter you're looking for. Use `$rand[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for - the regex is quite crude.

```
$urls=array(
    'domain.com/index/book-one-d_123456',
    'domain.com/index/book-one-r_123456'
);

$pttn='@(.*)(d_(\d+))|(.*)(r_(\d+))@i';
foreach( $urls as $url ){

    preg_match( $pttn, $url, $matches );
    $matches=array_filter( $matches );
    if( !empty( $matches ) )print_r( array_values( $matches ) );
}
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain.com/index/book-one-d_123456
    [1] => domain.com/index/book-one-
    [2] => d_123456
    [3] => 123456
)
Array
(
    [0] => domain.com/index/book-one-r_123456
    [1] => domain.com/index/book-one-
    [2] => r_123456
    [3] => 123456
)
```

From the output you can decide which items you wish to process further...

Answer (score 0):

Given your example URLs, `$rand[1]` is going to be `index` which is not the delimiter you're looking for. Use `$rand[2]` instead of `$rand[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally hate regex, so I believe there is a lot simpler way of doing what you need to do!

```
<?php
$url='domain.com/index/book-one-r_123456';
$ex=explode('_',$url);
    if(substr($ex[0],-1)=='d') { //checking if last letter is d
        //do some code, random code is $ex[2];, letter is d
    } elseif(substr($ex[0],-1)=='r') { //checking if last letter is r
        //do some code, random code is $ex[2]; letter is r
    }
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: @mario heh, maybe it is! I always had problems with that regexes, so I prefer using this instead :)